# I need a solution to find cost price ,tax,commission from a total amount in php

Tags: php

I am badly stuck for couple of weeks for a solution.Suppose I have a total price of Rs. 1000, And the breakup of this amount is costprice+10% commission of the costprice+18% TAX of the costprice=1000.

So i am finding a solution to get costprice,commission,tax in PHP. Please help me out!

Comment: Could you edit the question and show the program you have tried??

Comment: The data is insufficient. Do you want if someone enters an amount in an input field, the values should breakup as you said then display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a programming problem but a simple problem in basic arithmetic.

The total of cost price plus commission plus tax is the selling price.

With the numbers provided we get

```
              cost price * 1     plus
commission:   cost price * 0.1   plus
tax:          cost price * 0.18
              -----------------
              selling price
```

From this we can see that the selling price is 1.28 * cost price.

Now we can work backwards:

```
cost price = selling price / 1.28
tax = cost price * 0.18 = (selling price/1.28) * 0.18
commission = cost price * 0.10 = (selling price/1.28) * 0.1
```

Converting that to PHP:

```
<?php
$sellingPrice = 1000;
$taxPercent = 0.18;
$commPercent = 0.10;

$costPrice = $sellingPrice/(1+$taxPercent +$commPercent);
$taxAmount = $costPrice * $taxPercent;
$commAmount = $costPrice * $commPercent;
```